# How to go to the next page within the same URL of UK Currys?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-click

Hi I want to scrape the data from UK Currys. The web is (https://www.currys.co.uk/appliances/laundry/washing-machines/freestanding-washing-machines).

But different pages have the same URL.  I tried to use Selenium or `execute_script` to turn to the next page. Unfortunately, I could not make it.

I used two method.
First one:

```
next_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='product-search-results']/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div[26]/div[1]/div/div[3]/ul/li[6]/a")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_btn)
driver.quit()
```

Second one:

```
next_page = driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("#product-search-results > div.row.refinement-section > div.col-sm-12.col-lg-9.device-show-width > div.row.product-grid.list-view.justify-content-center > div.col-12.grid-footer > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.pagination-wrapper.pagination.justify-content-center.d-lg-block.d-xl-block.d-none > ul > li.first-last.page-item.pagination-arrrow-next > a")')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();',next_page)
```

Neither of them could go to the next page.

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] In addition also provide explicid error details. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try first to scroll to button before clicking:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

next_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='product-search-results']/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div[26]/div[1]/div/div[3]/ul/li[6]/a")))
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(next_btn).perform()
next_btn.click()
```

Comment: I think the last sentence is "next_btn.click()"
I tried it. The webdriver did not go to the next page. Sorry. It did not work.